# Indirect variables access in C not C++

Tags: c

is it possible to access variable value through other variable, as below

```
char var[30];
char buffer[30];

strcpy(buffer, "ABC");

/*variable var is holding the "buffer" variable name as string*/ 
strcpy(var,"buffer")
```

is there a way to access the buffer variable value "ABC", through variable var. ?

Answer (score 3):

Not in any practical way in C, and you don't really want to anyway.  Tying your program logic to the names of your variables is a horrible idea.  Typically I see people attempt this when what they really need is some sort of collection type (and array, a map, whatever).

How about filling us in on the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Per your comment:

> I need to have dynamic debug messages, I have a file which contain each function variables that I want to print.

Use stringification in a macro:

```
#define str(s) #s

int main() {
    int bar;
    str(bar) /* replaced by "bar" */
}
```

Comment: I need to have dynamic debug messages, I have a file which contain each function variables that I want to print.

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean to access the symbol table?  Scalars are named but they they contain values.  In C the executable does not contain symbol names.  For thay you have to look at symbol table which is output from the compiler.

Comment: not symbol table my dear, it is normal text file, our devlopment team is thinking to put the variables that they wish to print thier values, into a text file, then print these variables value, we don't want to modify the program by putting printf each time when we need to know the variable value.

Comment: @TarekAbulNaga: so you want to print the value of arbitrary variables from anywhere in the program?  Well I can't help you there, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Not without significant boiler plate code. Variable names are eliminated at compile-time.

In theory, you *could* store a map from variable names to a pointer to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. If you want indirect access, then declare a pointer and assign `var` to it.

```
char *forVar = var;

// Now you can access/modify via [] operator.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [union](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/)

For example:

```
union example {
    char var[40];
    char buffer[40];
} e1;

strcpy(e1.var, "ABC");

printf("%s is same as %s", e1.var, e1.buffer);
```

Comment: I need to have dynamic debug messages in my C program.
 I have a file which contains each function variables that I want to print.
 I am reading this file and stored the variables name in a variable called for example  L_sVarName, so L_sVarName is having the name of the variable that I want to print it's value.

That’s why I post my question

L_sVarName =”L_sName”  /* The variable in the file which I want to print */
L_sName =”ABC”

So I need to find out a way to print the variable L_sName value “ABC” by L_sVarName

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to log some variables when they are written to/read from/passed to functions etc?

Doing this with compiled C is difficult, as mentioned, especially if you are optimising your executable (-0n on the compile statement), in which case some of the variables can disappear completely, or get re-used by other variables.

**Using GDB**

Having said that, I know gdb can log variable access and that sort of stuff. If you were to write a python script (see http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html), you should be able to write a script to log variable content.

See this question for more: [Do specific action when certain breakpoint hits in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517423/do-specific-action-when-certain-breakpoint-hits-in-gdb)

**On demand only, using pre-compiler scripting**

Alternatively, if you just wanted to do it on demand, you'd be better off using a pre-processing script to add in custom macro's or similar, using a csv file as input:

```
for each line in CSV:
  read variable_name, file_name, variable_type
  find all occurrences of variable_name in file_name
  for each occurrence
    insert printf(....)
```

**On demand only, using macros**

Good luck. There isn't a nice way to do it, because you'd generally need some sort of lookup, and you'd need a way of selectively outputting variables to your print function. In some cases you could do something like:

```
static char _LOGGED_VAR_001 = 'z';
static char _LOGGED_VAR_002 = 'z';

#define cMyVar           _LOGGED_VAR_001
#define LOG_ALL_VARS()   printf("Vals: %c, %c", _LOGGED_VAR_001, _LOGGED_VAR_002)


void myFunc()
{
   char cMyVar; // Gets macro'd to _LOGGED_VAR_001 with LOCAL scope
   cMyVar = 'a'; // LOCAL scope _LOGGED_VAR_001 becomes 'a'
   LOG_ALL_VARS(); // At this point you print out the LOCAL _LOGGED_VAR_001 
                   // and the global _LOGGED_VAR_002
}
```

You would get `Vals: a, z`

This is pretty ugly, would only work for variables with local scope, messes round with memory consumption, could be error prone and is generally a *bad idea*.

**On demand, heap/stack dump**

If you have enough storage, you could dump all your memory on demand to a file. This probably wouldn't be very portable, depending on how it was done. I'm not sure how to do it though, in a reliable manner.

**Recommendation**

Use GDB for design-time diagnostics. It's what it's designed for :)

For (e.g.) analysing released code (automated bug reports), a full dump and then analysis at will might be relevant.