# How to do a specific action when ANY Unknown Breakpoint gets Hit in GDB

Tags: gdb, trace

I have read the following SO question:
[Do specific action when certain breakpoint hits in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517423/do-specific-action-when-certain-breakpoint-hits-in-gdb)

Here, we use 'command' to decide what to do when the SPECIFIED Breakboint Gets Hit.

My Question is:

Suppose I put Breakpoints on ALL the Functions matching a given pattern:

```
gdb$rbreak func_
```

=> 100 Breakpoints (say)

When I execute this Code, I want to do the SAME Action - on hitting Each of these functions.

Hence, I cannot define something like:

```
command break_point_number
```

// since I don't know how many breakpoints will be there

Can somebody please suggest me:

How can I do a specific action-set when ANY Breakpoint gets Hit in GDB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a new enough version of gdb you can use a range:

```
(gdb) rbreak whatever
... gdb creates breakpoints N, N+1, ..., M
(gdb) commands N-M
> stuff
> end
```

I forget exactly when this feature went in.

With an older version of gdb, I'm not sure it can easily be done.

It can be done with difficulty: use set logging to write output to a file, then "info break", then "shell" to run scripts to edit the file into gdb commands, then "source".  This is very painful.