# LLDB: silently continue after python script is done executing

Tags: python, debugging, lldb

I've written a python script that I am attaching to a watchpoint in LLDB, such as:

```
def wpCallback(frame, wp, internal_dict):
    ...
```

and I am attaching the callback with:

```
watchpoint command add -F commands.wpCallback watchpointID
```

I would like execution of the program to immediately resume after `wpCallback` is finished.  Currently, execution halts as the watchpoint normally would.  Is it possible to silently continue after the function is done?  Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517423/do-specific-action-when-certain-breakpoint-hits-in-gdb) answer it seems like you can do something like this in GDB:

```
break foo if x>0
commands
silent
do something...
cont
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call SBProcess.Continue() on your process in your watchpoint callback.  I.e. if you called the first argument to your callback `frame` do:

```
frame.thread.process.Continue()
```

That works for breakpoints, but seems to be broken for watchpoints in current TOT lldb.  It looks like it disables the watchpoint.  That's:

https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=28055

Comment: Have you tried that recently @jim?  With regular breakpoints in a lldb-python script it is not continuing.  I am getting the Frame from `frame = exe_ctx.frame` when my script starts.   `lldb-1103.0.22.10` . That is `XCode Version 11.6 `

Comment: You mention an exe_ctx as the way to get a frame, not the frame directly so I think you aren't talking about a Python breakpoint callback but rather a Python based command?  I can't tell from your description what you are doing with enough specificity to start trying to reproduce what you are seeing.  If you have a particular case that's not working, its probably best to file a bug with http://bugs.llvm.org.

Comment: Thanks.  It continued when I got the `SBProcess` instance this way -> `target = debugger.GetSelectedTarget()` and `process = target.GetProcess()`.  I put another SO ticket as I am missing something for the pretty way to achieve this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205500/continue-after-python-lldb-script-has-finished